# Why is the Present Perfect Continuous used in the sentence "You must have been drinking!"?

Tags: grammar

Why is the sentence "You must have drunk something" incorrect, but the sentence "You must have been drinking" correct?

Comment: You must have _drunk_ something is correct, is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: "You must have drink something" is wrong because ***drink*** should be a Past Participle - "You must have ***drunk*** something". OR a "Past Tense" verb, as in "It must be ***that*** you ***drank*** something".

Answer (score 1):

To say that someone has had (alcoholic) drink after drink after drink, we use the perfect continuous, the continuous underscoring the idea of repetitive or ongoing behavior, and the perfect indicating the relevance of that past behavior to some point in the future relative to that past behavior. Since **must** doesn't have a past tense, we don't know the temporal context from your sentence alone:

> I got pulled over by the police on the way home today.
>
> -- You must have been drinking!
>
> I got pulled over by the police a few years ago on my way home.
>
> -- You must have been drinking!

Comment: Despite ***today / a few years ago***, your examples don't represent Present / Past tense - they're both Past. I know it's a weak example, but Present Tense might be, say, *"I'm worried I'll get pulled over by the police when I drive home", "You must be drinking"* (if you weren't *currently* drinking, why else would you be worried?).

Comment: **must** being modal doesn't convey anything temporal and so **have been** and the time-phrases "today" and "a few years ago" are the only time markers.  The tense of **have been** is not simple past

Comment: The tense of ***have been*** isn't Simple Past (I never suggested otherwise), but it ***is*** Past. I addressed [***must** as a past tense verb*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/is-must-ever-grammatical-as-a-past-tense-verb) many years ago on ELU, but I would point out that not ***all*** modal verbs "lack" a Past Tense form. Consider ***can*** and ***could***.

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding what you mean by "it ***is*** past". Not sure what the referent of "it" is.  **must**  as you know does not show any tense markers differentiating present necessity from past necessity.

Comment: the referent of "it" is ***The tense of have been***, which I contend IS "past". It's irrelevant that ***have been*** happens to be used in the same utterance as ***must*** (which we obviously agree no longer inflects for tense, so ***mote*** it be! :)

Comment: But  "was" or "were" is the past tense of "be". Do you mean that the *meaning* of *must have been drinking* is equivalent to that of the simple past *surely were drinking*  and that there is therefore no aspectual sense of the  perfect involved?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then ***Yes*** - we say *must have been drinking* because that's the idiomatically established form, but normally the speaker has no interest in the fact that he's using a *continuous* verb form. Semantically, it's the same as *must have **had a drink*** - it's just that we don't use that tense very often in that *specific* context. But *I notice you and John seem to be avoiding each other. I assume you **have been arguing*** and *I assume you **had an argument*** are both equally idiomatic.

Comment: **had a drink** and **drinking** have very different meanings. "had a drink" means you finished one whereas  **drinking** means either you were in the process of drinking one or were having *multiple* drinks. So a speaker would definitely have an interest in that choice. On the other hand, if there's no past tense of **must** and there's no other choice but to use "have been" when speaking of past necessity with **must**, then you might challenge the assertion that "have been drinking" retains the aspectual significance of the perfect in such situations.

Comment: You seem to interpret English based on logic, rather than what people actually say and mean. To *have been drinking* and *have had a drink* are synonymous for almost everyone in almost every context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  To have had a drink and to have been drinking are not perfectly synonynominus [hic] for nearly everyone.  You're the one who's taking the logical position, not me.  The logical position is that a beverage has gone down the person's gullet in either case. The linguistic position is that there's a nuanced difference.

Answer (score 1):

*You must have been drinking* implies that the person being addressed is obviously under the influence of alcohol, so they must have been spending some time having repeated drinks.This is why the continuous tense is used.

*You must have* **drunk** *something* doesn't imply multiple alcoholic drinks.

Answer (score 0):

'must' is a modal verb and after modal verbs infinitives are used. There are 8 types of infinitives in English: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive

'must have drink' doesn't match any of these infinitives because 'drink' is not a past participle.

'must have been drinking' matches one of these infinitives. It's a perfect progressive infinitive (have been + ...ing)